# Describe the geometry of the variety $V(xy+xz+yz)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I want to describe the geometry of the variety $V(xy+xz+yz)$ but I'm a little unclear on the rules regarding reducing varieties.

Is it correct for me to rewrite the variety $V(xy+xz+yz)=V(xy) \cap V(xz) \cap V(yz)$? In which case $V(xy+xz+yz)=(0,0,0)$?

Answer (score 1):

No -- you can simply plug in values to see that this is not true (for example, $(1, 1, -1/2)$ is also a solution).

In terms of the geometry, this is cut out by one equation, and so should have codimension exactly equal to $1$, i.e. dimension $2$. But you end up with something of dimension zero.

Also, the rule I think you're trying to use is that
$$
V(I + J) = V(I) \cap V(J)
$$
where $I, J$ are *ideals*. Note that $(xy + yz + xz)$ is very different from the ideal $(xy)+(yz)+(xz)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you're right I think I got confused with that other rule. Do you have any advice on how it can be done?

Comment: @Munkres Depends on what you mean by describing it. It has dimension two, and note that, since it is cut out by homogeneous equations, it is the affine cone lying over some variety of dimension one less. In fact, the geometry (say over R) of this variety is just an infinite cone that is rotated (notice that if you intersect this variety with a hyperplane, say, $z=c$, you get a conic section!)